# My Postgres RDS Database is constantly reastarting suddenly due to heavyconsumption of memory. Not sure why it is happening suddenly

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

```
The database process was killed by the OS due to excessive memory consumption. It is recommended to tune your database workload and/or parameter usage to reduce memory consumption.

2022-03-07 12:17:57.302 GMT [9230] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 12:17:57.302 GMT [9230] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 12:17:57.302 GMT [9230] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 12:17:57 UTC::@:[9230]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.adaptive_autovacuum"
2022-03-07 12:17:57 UTC::@:[9230]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.enable_plan_management"
2022-03-07 12:17:57 UTC::@:[9230]:LOG: database system is shut down
Postgres Shared Memory Value: 23067312128 bytes
2022-03-07 12:17:59.685 GMT [9858] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 12:17:59.686 GMT [9858] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 12:17:59.686 GMT [9858] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.adaptive_autovacuum"
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.enable_plan_management"
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:LOG: starting PostgreSQL 12.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5434
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5434
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:LOG: listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5434"
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:LOG: could not write file "pg_stat_tmp/pgss_query_texts.stat": No such file or directory
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:LOG: redirecting log output to logging collector process
2022-03-07 12:17:59 UTC::@:[9858]:HINT: Future log output will appear in directory "/rdsdbdata/log/error".
2022-03-07 12:20:10 UTC::@:[9859]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 12:20:10 UTC::@:[9859]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 12:20:30 UTC::@:[9859]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 12:20:30 UTC::@:[9859]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 12:26:50 UTC::@:[9859]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 12:26:50 UTC::@:[9859]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 13:43:53.670 GMT [22533] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:43:53.670 GMT [22533] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:43:53.670 GMT [22533] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 13:43:53 UTC::@:[22533]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.adaptive_autovacuum"
2022-03-07 13:43:53 UTC::@:[22533]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.enable_plan_management"
2022-03-07 13:43:53 UTC::@:[22533]:LOG: database system is shut down
Postgres Shared Memory Value: 23067312128 bytes
2022-03-07 13:43:54.922 GMT [22660] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:43:54.922 GMT [22660] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:43:54.922 GMT [22660] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 13:43:54 UTC::@:[22660]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.adaptive_autovacuum"
2022-03-07 13:43:54 UTC::@:[22660]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.enable_plan_management"
2022-03-07 13:43:54 UTC::@:[22660]:LOG: starting PostgreSQL 12.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
2022-03-07 13:43:54 UTC::@:[22660]:LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5434
2022-03-07 13:43:54 UTC::@:[22660]:LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5434
2022-03-07 13:43:54 UTC::@:[22660]:LOG: listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5434"
2022-03-07 13:43:55 UTC::@:[22660]:LOG: redirecting log output to logging collector process
2022-03-07 13:43:55 UTC::@:[22660]:HINT: Future log output will appear in directory "/rdsdbdata/log/error".
2022-03-07 13:45:11 UTC::@:[22732]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:45:11 UTC::@:[22732]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 13:45:30 UTC::@:[22732]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:45:30 UTC::@:[22732]:LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 13:49:25.588 GMT [8568] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:49:25.588 GMT [8568] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:49:25.590 GMT [8568] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 13:49:25 UTC::@:[8568]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.adaptive_autovacuum"
2022-03-07 13:49:25 UTC::@:[8568]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.enable_plan_management"
2022-03-07 13:49:25 UTC::@:[8568]:LOG: database system is shut down
Postgres Shared Memory Value: 23067312128 bytes
2022-03-07 13:49:26.803 GMT [8674] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:49:26.803 GMT [8674] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf"
2022-03-07 13:49:26.803 GMT [8674] LOG: skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/db/postgresql.auto.conf"
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.adaptive_autovacuum"
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:WARNING: unrecognized configuration parameter "rds.enable_plan_management"
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:LOG: starting PostgreSQL 12.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5434
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5434
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:LOG: listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5434"
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:LOG: redirecting log output to logging collector process
2022-03-07 13:49:26 UTC::@:[8674]:HINT: Future log output will appear in directory "/rdsdbdata/log/error".
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

Comment: Can you lower Shared Memory? Try 8 or 16 GB or so

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No, I actually reduced the load on database to go forward. Not yet solved actual issue